# Why only multiple "%" is accepted by printf?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

Following program give the output `%%`. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //code
    printf("%%%%");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> %%

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** a `%` **is** a valid conversion specifier for `printf()`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, for conversion specifiers,

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`. After the `%`, the following
>   appear in sequence:
>
> .....
>
> — A *conversion specifier* character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.

and, from paragraph 8, for `%` *as* a *conversion specifier character*

for `%` conversion specifier

> `%` A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
>   conversion specification shall be `%%`.

Your code has a pair of `%%`s.

Answer (score 0):

`Printf` function's first argument is a `format` represented by a `char*`, it's not a string.

That's why for printing an `int`,for example, you have to write `"%d"`. So `%` is a special character, if you only write `%` as format, the compiler won't be happy because it is waiting for something after the `%` (either d, p, x, s, f, ...).

However, by writing `%%` it means "Print me one escaped %". That's why `%%%%` prints `%%`

EDIT: If you want a function that prints exactly what you give, you can use `write`:

```
char* mystr = "%%%%";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, mystr, strlen(mystr));
```

Comment: `Printf function's first argument is a format represented by a char*, it's not a string.` .. can you elaborate?

Comment: `So % is a special character`..technically, it indicates _start of a conversion specifier_.

Comment: I mean, when printf is called, the `char*` is not directly written, it's preprocessed and so every special sequence of char is replaced. For example, `%s` is replaced by a char*

Comment: `preprocessed`? please enlight me.

Comment: Printf creates a `char*`where your options are replaced, so `%d` are replaced by the given int (after converting into a `char*), `%s` are replaced by the given strings, and so on...
After that, the resulting `char*` is written to STDOUT with the syscall `write`

Comment: ...and that happens in `preprocessing` ? Sorry, can you quote something?

Comment: I agree preprocessing may not be the correct word. I am just saying what I learnt at University

Comment: ...and I'm just trying to exactly point that out. `preprocessing` has a special meaning in C. Choose some alternative wording. :)

Comment: Oh I understand. I am sorry about this, I learnt in French so I don't always choose the right translation

Comment: Nothing to be sorry, it's ok, we understand. Happy to help.